# My jQuery files won't load in any browser

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I'm currently trying to build a website from templates using Bootstrap but I can't load any of the JS files I have in my distant servers.
I've tried the whole lot of solutions this website was suggesting, but in vain : when i refresh a webpage, no JS file appears in the resources.

Here's how my  looks :

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/3-col-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script href="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script href="js/grindhouseleather.js"></script>
<script href="js/jquery.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>GrindHouse Leather</title>
</head>
```

The body of the signup form I'm currently working on :

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
    <form role="form">
        <h2>Please Sign Up <small>It's free and always will be.</small></h2>
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="display_name" id="display_name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Display Name" tabindex="3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="4">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="info" tabindex="7">I Agree</button>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="t_and_c" id="t_and_c" class="hidden" value="1">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                 By clicking <strong class="label label-primary">Register</strong>, you agree to the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="7"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Sign In</a></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="t_and_c_m" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms & Conditions</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Terms and conditions go here -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">I Agree</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery script I'm trying to use :

```
$(function () {
$('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

    // Settings
    var $widget = $(this),
        $button = $widget.find('button'),
        $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
        color = $button.data('color'),
        settings = {
            on: {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
            },
            off: {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
            }
        };

    // Event Handlers
    $button.on('click', function () {
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
        $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
        updateDisplay();
    });
    $checkbox.on('change', function () {
        updateDisplay();
    });

    // Actions
    function updateDisplay() {
        var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

        // Set the button's state
        $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

        // Set the button's icon
        $button.find('.state-icon')
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

        // Update the button's color
        if (isChecked) {
            $button
                .removeClass('btn-default')
                .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
        }
        else {
            $button
                .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                .addClass('btn-default');
        }
    }

    // Initialization
    function init() {

        updateDisplay();

        // Inject the icon if applicable
        if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
            $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i>');
        }
    }
    init();
});
});
```

The jQuery.js is the 2.1.1 version, and I don't get any error messages in the browsers... What's wrong ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: You need to use src as in `<script src=` not `href=` - Guys, please let the user delete this himself instead of answering it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your script imports with the below and try:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/grindhouseleather.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

The script tag has 'src' attribute and not 'href'

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: I AM SO DUUUUUUUUMB !! Thanks a lot, that answers a lot of questions !

Comment: Happens with the best of us :)

Comment: It was answered in my first comment. This question was not worth answering and now cannot be deleted without a moderator.